# Duplicate List Views After Deployment

Tags: deployment, list-view

Every now and then, our users report that some list views get duplicated, and this usually occurs after a deployment. Our list views are tracked in source control and deployed by a deployment pipeline.

Based on the existence of [this knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000331580&type=1), I imagine salesforce is aware of the problem, but the documented resolution of fixing it manually seems insufficient.

It also lacks info on how the problem occurs in the first place so I'm not sure how to work around it, particularly in our deploy pipeline. Any help?

Comment: From the knowledge article: _The duplicate list views can be observed via the API_ and recommended solution: _Delete the duplicated list view and then re-deploy it to the impacted environment_.  Can your pipeline call the API to detect the dupe and then delete+redeploy?

Comment: Do you deploy everything (list views) each time or is this occurring when you make changes to a list view and expect it to be deployed?